# Pandas lambda function works only on single column not multiple

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I'm trying to apply a simple function (eliminating spaces) across multiple columns of a pandas DataFrame. However, while the .apply() method works properly on a single column, it doesn't work properly over multiple columns. Example:

```
#Weird Pandas behavior
######
#Input
df = pd.DataFrame ({'a' : ["7  7","5 3"],
                 'b' : ['f o', 'b  r'],
                 'c' : ["77","53"]})
print(df)

      a     b   c
0  7  7   f o  77
1   5 3  b  r  53

df[["a","b"]]=df[["a","b"]].apply(lambda x: x.replace(" ",""))
print(df)

      a     b   c
0  7  7   f o  77
1   5 3  b  r  53


df2=copy.deepcopy(df)
print(df2)

      a     b   c
0  7  7   f o  77
1   5 3  b  r  53

df2["a"]=df2["a"].apply(lambda x: x.replace(" ",""))
print(df2)

    a     b   c
0  77   f o  77
1  53  b  r  53
```

As you can see, df doesn't change at all when I try to apply the "replace" operation to two columns, but the same dataset (or rather a copy of it) does change when I run the same operation on a single column. How can I remove spaces from two or more columns at once using the .apply() syntax?

I tried passing in the arguments '[a]' (nothing happens) and 'list(a)' (nothing happens) to df[].

Comment: use a string function instead : ``df[['a','b']].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(" ", ""))`` you are working on replace whitespace **within** a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function directly:

```
df[['a','b']] = df[['a','b']].replace(' ','', regex=True)
```

#### Output:

[image: dataframe]

Answer (score 2):

When you pass multiple columns, `x` is a pandas series, not the individual column values. You need to use `.str.replace()` to operate on each column.

```
df[["a","b"]]=df[["a","b"]].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(" ",""))
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is it not a pandas series when I pass in one column e.g. df[["a"]]? And is there some way to get the contents of a pandas series instead of the series itself? I'm used to R where data tables have columns that are vectors of a single type, not series.